# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC - Populating a viewmodel from list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently I am dabbling in ASP.NET Core 6.0 and got stuck on trying to populate a view model.

I have the following linq(?) query (is it even called that?)

```
var fotoGeneratedNames = _context.Foto 
                                 .Where(x => fotoIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                 .Select(x => x.generatedName)
                                 .ToList();
```

Controller code

```
// Diese Methode gibt die notwendigen Daten für eine spezifische Gallerie zurück 
public IActionResult Gallerie(int id) 
{ 
    // instantiert neue Var mit dem Expose Viewmodel Gallerie
    // var viewModelExposeGallerie = new ViewModelExposeGallerie(); 

    // nimm gallerieId, such alle FotoIds aus associationtable raus
    var fotoIds = (from a in _context.GallerieFoto 
                   where a.GallerieId == id select a.FotoId).ToList();

    // Nimm alle elemente in der tabelle Foto mit den Elementen in fotoIds und mach eine Liste mit den generiertenNamen der Fotos
    var fotoGeneratedNames = _context.Foto
                                     .Where(x => fotoIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                     .Select(x => x.generatedName)
                                     .ToList();

    return View(fotoGeneratedNames);
}
```

This is my view model

```
namespace abc.Models
{
    public class ViewModelExposeGallerie
    {
        public string FotoName { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Now - what I tried was a foreach akin to

```
foreach var x in fotoGeneratedNames 
    ViewModelExposeGallerie.FotoName = fotoGeneratedNames
```

but this only replaced the value and did not give me a list, that I could use in the view.

Thankful for any hints, have a good one!

Comment: Could you show us want you want to do in view?

Comment: pretty much just something like 

```
@model ienumerable abc.models.viewmodel

@foreach {

<img src @item > </img>
}

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Gallerie(int id) { 

    ...
             
    var fotoGeneratedNames = _context.Foto
        .Where(x => fotoIds.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(x => x.generatedName)
        .ToList();

    return View(fotoGeneratedNames);
}
```

You are returning a `List<string>` but not `List<ViewModelExposeGalleri>` type

Your view should be as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@foreach (var name in Model)
{
    <div>@name</div>
}
```

Unsure what you want to render for the HTML element, so I illustrate the demo with `<div>` element.

---

If you return `List<ViewModelExposeGalleri>` from the Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Gallerie(int id) { 

    ...
             
    var fotoGeneratedList = _context.Foto
        .Where(x => fotoIds.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(x => new ViewModelExposeGallerie
        {
            FotoName = x.generatedName
        })
        .ToList();

    return View(fotoGeneratedList);
}
```

```
@model IEnumerable<abc.models.ViewModelExposeGalleri>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item.FotoName</div>
}
```